# Appending script element does not request Google API

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm loading a third party `script` element provided by Google:

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var xml = '<script defer="true" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>';
h.appendChild(document.importNode(new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml,'application/xml').childNodes[0],true));
```

None of the browsers (Waterfox, Chrome, IE11, IE15) are throwing errors or warnings, they are simply *not* requesting the file from Google (nothing displayed in the network requests). I've verified error reporting is enabled/maximized sensitivity in all those browsers.

This scenario is on content that is loaded only via AJAX so I can *not* load the script along with everything else. Why is the script not even attempting the request? This is from both localhost and live websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler to just create a script element than go through all that xml parsing

```js
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

var scr = document.createElement('script')
scr.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js';
h.appendChild(scr);

scr.onload = () => console.log('Loaded')
```

Comment: Not sure why this works though my code does not. ︎ Any way I *can* condense this and it will be shorter ... oh, and it works which you know, is what matters most. Thank you! ︎

Comment: Right ...  I'm not even going to guess why yours isn't...have personally never even used `document.importNode`

Comment: I code everything using XML + HTML5, so that is HTML5 served as application/xhtml+xml because of it's strict handling of everything and `document.importNode` is used a lot when doing AJAX related stuff. Also, I'll accept after the timer runs out.

Comment: Seems like overkill to me. Also thought xhtml was pretty much deprecated. Haven't used it in years either

Comment: It's not XHTML, it's HTML5 using the XML parser. What version of HTML you use and which parser (HTML or XML) are not one-in-the-same.

Comment: My bad. Only time I've done much with xml client side I was using jQuery and it makes working with xml trivial...basically using normal jQuery html methods on it

Answer (score 0):

This is because your head is most probably finished loading by the time your javascript code tries to insert html to it. Therefore a solution would be to somehow add  tag to your html before it starts loading.

Comment: Not really, I've done this a tons of times, just never with third-party domains. You probably could have done this (charlietfl's answer) back in the Netscape 4 days if `createElement` was supported back then.

Comment: You must be right. Sorry for confusion. Then, maybe it has something to do with same-origin policy combined with your approach of adding html, don't know :-) I am just theorizing :)

Comment: I was thinking that too though usually it's from code loaded from the server, not code already ...in the code?